# ReactJS, useLayoutEffect with document, empty values

Tags: reactjs, use-effect

I'm trying to disable two elements getting by class like this:

```
const disableMonthAndYear = () => {
  const cellsMonth = document.getElementsByClassName('ant-picker-month-btn');
  const cellsYear = document.getElementsByClassName('ant-picker-year-btn');
  console.log('cellsMonth', cellsMonth);
  for (let i = 0; i < cellsMonth.length; i++) {
    console.log('i', i); // not entering here
    cellsMonth[i].disabled = true;
  }
  for (let i = 0; i < cellsYear.length; i++) {
    cellsYear[i].disabled = true;
  }
};

useLayoutEffect(() => {
  disableMonthAndYear();
}, []);
```

I thought on using `useLayoutEffect` because I wanted to call the `disableMonthAndYear` function only when DOM was all loaded, because in the `console.log('cellsMonth', cellsMonth);` I'm getting empty arrays, but when I click them I can see the values inside...
[image]

With a `setTimeout` works ok, but that's not the idea, how should I ensure that the const defined by those `document.getElementsByClassName(` are fullfill with data before changing it's `disabled` properties?

Comment: Dont use `document` in any way `document.getElementsByClassName` `document.getElementsById` and so on. Its vanilla js stuff. Its only acceptable in the first line whenever you are rendering DOM. ONLY place to do it once. You are not using react as its intended. This is dirty. Use references `useRef` or, if you are mapping your tables, then just dont render in specific cells that shouldint be rendered. anything! By removing this dirty way you also fix the issue of not knowing if you have data or not and so on. Leave everything to React

Comment: Ok but I can't add a ref to an external library, that library (ant date rangepicker) has only classes on its elements

Comment: So you are passing a object, with data, to it? Then why not just filter out the data before yuo pass it so the component just never recieves the data you do not want to display?

Comment: That's no related to the question. I want to disable to divs from an external library, currently it is working by using a setTimeout and setting disable true to the DOM but I wonder if there's another way to do it, with ref would be ok if all where React components

Comment: Every component in ant design (seems what you using) has a lot of API's how to modify it. Including for tables to make a custom render of a specific column meaning for your `month` and `year` columns you can add a simple `if` check to render it or not or, if you wanna render but with `disabled` atribute - you cna do that too. Its hard to answer exactly how to help out when  we do not know exactl situation. What component are you passing info to? what does it do? Cuz what you provided us is a dirty react code that shouldint be used. plz update ur post with more info